# Need to implement timer (with nature of variable time intervals) in an android application

Tags: android, timer, timertask

My edited code.Here interval is the vector which stores the delays required and index is initialized to 0.I got my mistake.this is what I have been doing,

```
public class MainActivity{
private int index;
       //Some code and initializations

    public void startTimer{
     index=0;
    private Timer timer=new Timer();
    private TimerTask timertask=new MyTimerTask();
   // timer.schedule(timertask,0,1000);         //This line was causing trouble

    }

    private class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask
        {
                public void run() {     

           handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        int limit = interval.size();

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (index < limit) {
                Integer secondDelay = interval.get(k);
                Log.e(TAG, "index= " + index + " interval= " + secondDelay + " seconds");

                //Some code

                long delay = secondDelay * 1000;
                index++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            } else {
                handler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null); //Cancelling the handler.postDelayed
                Log.e(TAG, "Cancelling timer");
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    }, 0);
    }
}
}
```

The log output is after every 1 second.

The commented line was causing error.It should be
timer.schedule(timertask,0);  and now its working correctly.

Comment: Wait you are a little confused, index and k are not declared and you do not need to removeCallBacks e....timer.cancel!??! Please start from the code of my answer

Comment: I found out the error and have corrected it.Thanks,you were a great help

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue and I solved with an `Handler`

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            int minute = 0;
            @Override
            public void run() {
                {
                    Log.d("TAG", "next run after "+minute+" minutes");
                    long delay = minute * 60000;
                    minute++;
                    handler.postDelayed(this,delay);
                }
            }
        }, 0);
```

And this is the `logcat`

```
01-27 11:49:55.830 23761-23761/? D/TAG: next run after 0 minutes
01-27 11:49:55.945 23761-23761/? D/TAG: next run after 1 minutes
01-27 11:50:56.015 23761-23761/? D/TAG: next run after 2 minutes
01-27 11:52:56.115 23761-23761/? D/TAG: next run after 3 minutes
01-27 11:55:56.225 23761-23761/? D/TAG: next run after 4 minutes
...and so on
```

My example has minute interval but you can easily adapt it to seconds.

Hope it helps.

---

EDIT
I modified the example based on your comments

```
final ArrayList<Integer> interval = new ArrayList<>();
interval.add(1);
interval.add(5);
interval.add(10);
interval.add(3);

final Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    int index = 0;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        {

            if (index < interval.size()) {
                Integer secondDelay = interval.get(index);

                Log.d("TAG", "next run after " + secondDelay + " seconds");
                long delay = secondDelay * 1000;
                index++;
                handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
            } else {
                Log.d("TAG", "I finish");
            }

        }
    }
}, 0);
```

logcat:

```
01-27 17:51:09.940 28113-28113/? D/TAG: next run after 1 seconds
01-27 17:51:10.940 28113-28113/? D/TAG: next run after 5 seconds
01-27 17:51:15.950 28113-28113/? D/TAG: next run after 10 seconds
01-27 17:51:25.960 28113-28113/? D/TAG: next run after 3 seconds
01-27 17:51:28.965 28113-28113/? D/TAG: I finish
```

Comment: So you mean "delay" in handler.postDelayed should contain the variable time interval required?

Comment: Yes, and it increment automatically each item the anonymous runnable is called

Comment: According to your suggestion,I am using                            delay=interval.get(k)*1000;
handler.postDelayed(this,delay); where interval is a vector consisting of variable delays and k is the index,but if i use this then the output always differs by 1 second irrespective of the value at interval[k]

Comment: I update the answer with another example using an arraylist

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.But its still not working

Comment: edit the question and post your code...I runned my handler example and works....maybe you missed something.

Answer (score 0):

Forget `Timer`: it would be easier just to do this using sleep in a loop:

```
class MyTimerRunnable implements Runnable {
  @Override public void run() {
    for (int i = 1; i < 5; ++i) {
      try {
        Thread.sleep(/* for however long */);
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      System.out.println("Current:"+new Date());
    }
  }
}
```

and then just start this in its own `Thread` (e.g. `new Thread(new MyTimerRunnable()).start();`), or by submitting it to an `Executor`.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of created my own timer class using the `Handler` class (the one in `android.os` package). Here is a basic idea of it.

Your class contains a field of type `Handler`. You instantiate it in the constructor. You should also have a field called `interval`.

In the constructor, after you created the handler object, you call `postDelayed` on the handler. The method needs two parameter. The first one is a `Runnable` and the second is the delay in ms.

To write the runnable object, remember to call the handler's `postDelay` with exactly the same parameters again after you did what you wanted it to do.

And for the second parameter, just pass the field `interval`.

**tl;dr:** You see what I'm doing here? When the timer is constructed, you post an event that is going to happen after some time. When that event happened, do what you like and post another event that is going to happen after the same time.

To change the interval, just add a setter to set the `interval` object. And the next time the runnable gets run, it will post an event to be run after the new interval!

Here is the code for my timer class:

```
import android.os.Handler;

public class Timer {
    private Handler handler;
    private boolean paused;

    private int interval;

    private Runnable task = new Runnable () {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (!paused) {
                runnable.run ();
                Timer.this.handler.postDelayed (this, interval);
            }
        }
    };

    private Runnable runnable;

    public int getInterval() {
        return interval;
    }

    public void setInterval(int interval) {
        this.interval = interval;
    }

    public void startTimer () {
        paused = false;
        handler.postDelayed (task, interval);
    }

    public void stopTimer () {
        paused = true;
    }

    public Timer (Runnable runnable, int interval, boolean started) {
        handler = new Handler ();
        this.runnable = runnable;
        this.interval = interval;
        if (started)
            startTimer ();
    }
}
```

EDIT: after reviewing your question, it seems like that you are not using android but you tagged the question android. Anyway, if you are really not, just use a `javax.swing.Timer` that is way better. Look for the docs on Google!

Comment: the title of the post says "android" so it's seems that user use android but he don't know the existence of the Handler class, anyway great class!